# Prevent matplotlib to sort axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following test case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.arange(10)
x2 = np.hstack((np.linspace(0.12312, 3.94, 5), np.linspace(-10.0121, -9.333411, 5)))

y = 2.0 * x1

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot(x1, y)

fig = plt.figure(2)
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot(x2, y)

fig = plt.figure(3)
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot(x1, y)
ax.set_xticklabels(x2[ax.get_xticks().astype(int)])

plt.show()
```

I'd like to plot `figure(2)` with `x2` original ordering. But when I use it with `pyplot.plot` it's automatically sorted and it messes up my axis.

I can manually set the ticklabels like in `figure(3)` but I don't get automatic axis scaling, formatting and so on.
I could probably hack something myself with formatters, locators etc, but first I'd like to ask: is there a *proper way* to achieve what I'd like?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with this kind of plot. You can manage it somehow, like you did it with figure(3) but it's totally against intuition or good practice. Normally if you are looking on a 2D plot you assume that each axis is a continuous scale (ascending or descending). It can be even logarithmic or other scale.

Comment: Fair enough, but the thing is that my function is produced by a sequential integer input, but the x axis represents something else, let's say float values in no particular order. I guess custom tick labels is the way to go here, but I kind of liked the idea to let matplotlib choose which precision to use for optimal label spacing, it somewhat like reinventing the wheel doing this myself. Maybe there's a formatter that does exactly what I want but I cannot find it.

Comment: So, what you want to plot is something where you can see which value belongs to which input. Like important is x-y plus where is it in the sequence. Is that correct?

Comment: Right, if it helps, one particular plot where I could benefit from something like this is a DFT plot, where the integer range representation would be _DFT bins_, while the float unordered one would be _frequencies_

Comment: As far as I know they set the tick labels for spectorgrams like you did. Ideas you could eventually consider to solve your problem (not technical solutions for your questions, rather choosing different ways to visualise, at the end it depends what data you have):
- Boxplot: x-axis is the sequence, y-axis is a value, standard deviation the second value
- Normal plot where x is the sequence or time and at the data points on the plot you can add a text field containing the x2 values